# Ejecting expo does not eject IOS

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, metro-bundler

I have 2 issues, the second resulted from attempting to solve the first. My first issue occured when trying to run my app on Expo Go, it wouldn't load no matter what i tried. I used `npx expo start`, `npx expo start --lan` `expo-cli start tunnel` and other commands i found online.

I ended up getting an error that read

> **Console Warning**
> Cannot Connect to Metro.
> Try the following to fix the issue:
> -Ensure that Metro is running and available on the same network
> -Ensure that the Metro URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
> URL: IPV4:PORT

So i tried to find AppDelegate file which i couldn't find anywhere, and from a tutorial online i found out that i need to eject Expo which i did, it ended up ejecting an android file but no IOS file im not sure if this is connected to my issue but i thought it might be helpful to mention anyway. Thanks for the help in advance and i apologise if this is a stupid question, because i've just started coding and am following some tutorials.